# Does an integral without an integrand imply the integrand is $1$?

Tags: convention

This is a question concerning mathematical convention.  If we see something like

$$
\int_a^b dx
$$

Does this imply that

$$
\int_a^b dx = \int_a^b 1\ dx\text{?}
$$

Comment: yes,that is correct

Comment: Despite being correct, a more suitable interpretation is that the infinite sum of the infinitesimal portion $dx$ over the interval $[a,b]$ equals the measure of the interval, namely $b-a$.

Comment: I agree with @7raiden7. The $dx$ should be considered part of the integrand itself. So that integral is not without an integrand.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $1$ is implied in $\int_a^b\, dx = \int_a^b 1\, dx$, similar to how people write 
$$\int_a^b \frac{\,dx}{x^2} \quad \text{instead of }\quad \int_a^b \frac{1}{x^2}\,dx$$

Notation has its critics, as pretty much every notation for integrals. I vaguely remember a book suggesting $\int_a^b 1(x)\, dx$, because the double appearance of $x$ should remind the reader that it's a dummy variable, like an index of summation. I'm not expecting this to catch on, though.

---

At least nobody is writing $\displaystyle \sum_{i=a}^b$  instead of $\displaystyle \sum_{i=a}^b 1$.